# Chrome addon to view <title> via double-click

Tags: html, chrome, productivity

By default, when we hover a mouse over  a tab and freeze it for a consecutive ~500 mseconds, Chrome will show the title of the page in a tooltip, e.g.:

[image: Chrome: tooltip showing a tab’s title]

(Btw, if you have a jittery mouse that is unable to remain still, you'll never be able to see the tooltip.)

Is there a Chrome addon to show the title of the page by double-clicking on the tab?

The text must be "usual text", such that it can be selected and copied. (Contrast that with text within a tooltip which cannot be *operated* on.) E.g. after double-clicking the tab, this might be what we see:

[image: Chrome: overlay, with a close button, showing the page’s title]

Comment: There's not going to be any extension that detects click *on the tab at the top*, because extensions (or anything else) can't capture a click at that part. However there may be extensions where you click the extension's icon to show the title

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ, I.c. hopefully they could add that in the future for extensions. I think that currently plugins might be able to achieve that, though I'm not sure. Btw, do you know of a searchable page which lists all the functions/capabilities of extensions and plugins?

Comment: Nope - the extension API doesn't support clicking *on the tab* thing at the top :( And sorry - no, but there's always google!

Comment: I just came across this question again, not sure if you're still looking for something like this but you could have a bookmarklet that shows the title in a selectable text box if you want! Let me know if you're still interested and I'll try writing a quick bookmarklet :)